# xampp or apache not work in some page WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp, hosting

I install xampp on windows server 2003.

At first i move my wp on server for hosting .

but when i open index page i know every thing work good but 3 image source is same :

```
<img class="cover" src="<? bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/s1.jpg" alt="[HTML & CSS]"/>
```

or some data :

```
<li class="<? if(is_home()) echo 'current_page_item'; ?>"><a href="#"> first page</a></li>
```

and in all page include at the first :

```
<?

/**

 * @package WordPress

 * @subpackage magazine_obsession

 */



require_once('fn-admin.php');

require_once('thman-settings.php');

require_once('thman-settings-pages.php');



add_action('admin_menu', 'thman_add_menu'); 



?>
```

and wp-admin not show to me when i try to go to wp-admin show top message .

What is the problem? why same php file execute good but some of them no?
Is that problem form apache or wp or xammp ?

How I can solve it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check your logs in /var/log/httpd and set "display_errors E_ALL" in /etc/php.ini  You develop in windows workstation and deploy to unix server?

Comment: last server is unix new server is windows

Comment: First of all you need analize logs, check DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR in your including pathes.

Comment: All examples you've shown are using short tags. Could it perhaps be `short_open_tag` php.ini setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All examples you have posted are using the short (`<? ?>`) tag variation. You could either consider changing them to `<?php ?>` or perhaps the easier solution would be simply enable [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) in your php.ini